# python TicTacToe while

Tags: python, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

There's a TicTacToe game which is almost completed. I only have problem with my while loop. I don't know why I can't get "X wins" or "O wins", only "Draw". Thanks for help!

I don't know what more should I write, but there's a "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." message, so I'm writing this.

```
x_o = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

x_wins = {'row1_X': "X" == x_o[0] and "X" == x_o[1] and "X" == x_o[2],
          'row2_X': "X" == x_o[3] and "X" == x_o[4] and "X" == x_o[5],
          'row3_X': "X" == x_o[6] and "X" == x_o[7] and "X" == x_o[8],
          'col1_X': "X" == x_o[0] and "X" == x_o[3] and "X" == x_o[6],
          'col2_X': "X" == x_o[1] and "X" == x_o[4] and "X" == x_o[7],
          'col3_X': "X" == x_o[2] and "X" == x_o[5] and "X" == x_o[8],
          'slant1_X': "X" == x_o[0] and "X" == x_o[4] and "X" == x_o[8],
          'slant2_X': "X" == x_o[2] and "X" == x_o[4] and "X" == x_o[6]
          }

o_wins = {'row1_O': "O" == x_o[0] and "O" == x_o[1] and "O" == x_o[2],
          'row2_O': "O" == x_o[3] and "O" == x_o[4] and "O" == x_o[5],
          'row3_O': "O" == x_o[6] and "O" == x_o[7] and "O" == x_o[8],
          'col1_O': "O" == x_o[0] and "O" == x_o[3] and "O" == x_o[6],
          'col2_O': "O" == x_o[1] and "O" == x_o[4] and "O" == x_o[7],
          'col3_O': "O" == x_o[2] and "O" == x_o[5] and "O" == x_o[8],
          'slant1_O': "O" == x_o[0] and "O" == x_o[4] and "O" == x_o[8],
          'slant2_O': "O" == x_o[2] and "O" == x_o[4] and "O" == x_o[6]
          }

print("---------")
print("|", " ", " ", " ", "|")
print("|", " ", " ", " ", "|")
print("|", " ", " ", " ", "|")
print("---------")

coordinates = [['1', '3'], ['2', '3'], ['3', '3'], ['1', '2'], ['2', '2'], ['3', '2'], ['1', '1'], ['2', '1'],
               ['3', '1']]

count = 0

empty_places = coordinates

while True not in x_wins.values() and True not in o_wins.values() and x_o.count("X") + x_o.count("O") != 9:
    move = input("Enter the coordinates: ").split(" ")
    if move in empty_places:
        ind = coordinates.index(move)
        empty_places[ind] = [" ", " "]
        if count % 2 == 0:
            x_o[ind] = "X"
            count += 1
        else:
            x_o[ind] = "O"
            count += 1
        print("----------")
        print("|", x_o[0], x_o[1], x_o[2], "|")
        print("|", x_o[3], x_o[4], x_o[5], "|")
        print("|", x_o[6], x_o[7], x_o[8], "|")
        print("----------")
    elif move not in empty_places and move in coordinates:
        print("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!")
    elif not move[0].isdigit() and not move[1].isdigit():
        print("You should enter numbers!")
    elif move not in empty_places and int(move[0]) > 3 or int(move[1]) > 3:
        print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")

if True in x_wins.values():
    print("X wins")
elif True in o_wins.values():
    print("O wins")
elif True not in x_wins.values() and True not in o_wins.values():
    print("Draw")
```

Comment: It seems that you create ‘x_wins’ at the beginning and never change it again. All the values start off ‘False’ and never change. Same goes for ‘o_wins’.

Comment: `x_wins ` is never modified,it's computed at first wregarding values of `x_o`, but when you modify `x_o` it does not dynamicaly change `x_wins` or y_wins, no no

Answer (score 0):

You're only defining `x_wins` and `o_wins` once, at the start of the program, so they will stay in their initial values for the entire run of the program, which is to say, filled entirely with `False`.  To fix this, you should make x_wins and o_wins into *functions* that return the dictionary--that way, whenever you call `x_wins()` and `o_wins()`, it'll recalculate the dictionary and correctly determine if one of them won.

```py
def x_wins():
    return {'row1_X': "X" == x_o[0] and "X" == x_o[1] and "X" == x_o[2],
            'row2_X': "X" == x_o[3] and "X" == x_o[4] and "X" == x_o[5],
            'row3_X': "X" == x_o[6] and "X" == x_o[7] and "X" == x_o[8],
            'col1_X': "X" == x_o[0] and "X" == x_o[3] and "X" == x_o[6],
            'col2_X': "X" == x_o[1] and "X" == x_o[4] and "X" == x_o[7],
            'col3_X': "X" == x_o[2] and "X" == x_o[5] and "X" == x_o[8],
            'slant1_X': "X" == x_o[0] and "X" == x_o[4] and "X" == x_o[8],
            'slant2_X': "X" == x_o[2] and "X" == x_o[4] and "X" == x_o[6]
           }
```